# Divide and Conquer algorithm to make a word palidrome with minimum relocatation of letters

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I'm looking for a divide and conquer algorithm to solve the problem of making a word palindrome with minimum relocation of letters.

This algorithm is feasible for words such as `peept` which can convert to `petep` with two relocation between `t` and `p` (giving `peetp`) and then `t` and `e` (giving `petep`).

Is it possible to do this with divide and conquer?

This is not my homework. Just fun to know.

This is the algorithm I wrote in C#, but is this the best way with minimum replaces?

```c#
private string MakePalindrome(StringBuilder word, int i, int j)
{
    if (i == j)
    {
        return word[i].ToString();
    }
    if (i + 1 == j && word.Length%2 == 0)
    {
        return word[i] == word[j] ? word.ToString() : "infinite";
    }
    if (word[i] != word[j])
    {
        for (int k = j; k >= i; k--)
        {
            if (k == i)
                return "infinite";
            if (word[k] == word[i])
            {
                char ch = word[j];
                word[j] = word[k];
                word[k] = ch;
                replaceCounter++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    var palindrome = MakePalindrome(new StringBuilder(word.ToString(i+1, j-i-1)),i,j-2);
    if (palindrome == "infinite")
        return "infinite";
    return word[i] + palindrome + word[j];
}
```

Comment: Your homework won't get done for you here. Show us the code you've attempted, or the algorithm you've attempted to build.

Comment: Hi there. But It's not my homework. I graduated 5 years ago.. this is a problem that I worked about 3 hours on it, but nothing to find. And just I want to know the answer. Or if it is possible with divide and conquer or not.

Comment: Hint: start from both sides, working towards the middle.